# Tikz node inserts additional horizontal spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, spacing

The `\MyTikzMarkNode` below seems to be inserting additional horizontal space when used in math mode. How should the macro be defined so that the additional horizontal space is eliminated?

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyTikzMarkNode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline]\node[anchor=base](#1){#2};}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 \\
    F &= \MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 1}{$ma$}\MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 2}{$ma$}  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `inner sep=0` for nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Space which you observe is consequence of inner separation of node contens from its border. If you add to nodes option `inner xsep=0pt, this space will disappear:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyTikzMarkNode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline]\node[anchor=base,
                      inner xsep=0pt% by this the horizontal space beteen nodes disapear
                      ](#1){#2};}%

\begin{document}
\MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 1}{$ma$}\MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 2}{$ma$}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 \\
    F &= \MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 1}{$ma$}\MyTikzMarkNode{Node Name 2}{$ma$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I forgot about `inner sep`. I guess I can add this to my list of embarrassing questions.

Comment: Where do you keep the list?